# Remover fixed lenght do SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework

As os campos string das tabelas do meu banco de dados estão vindo com o fixed length como true.
Então se o tamanho é 60, e eu salvo uma string com tamanho de 30, ele preenche a string com espaços até o tamanho total. Se for no edmx e setar manualmente pra false funciona. Mas como setar isso pra false como padrão no SQL Server?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Cadê seu modelo EF Code First, pfv?

Comment: é database first

Comment: está normal, como sempre faço. nvarchar(60)

Comment: NVARCHAR ou NCHAR?

Comment: nvarchar(60)   ..

Comment: Depois ou antes do Fixed Length false?

Comment: reiniciei o serviço do sql server, atualizei o edmx e funcionou